# Merge multiple row of data into one in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm currently trying to create some kind of data gathering doc from a google form to recreate what happened during the day.
The idea is to have this form to be filled and send everytime something is happening without having the need to modifying it so it will create a partial entry each time as shown below

[image: Data gathered troughout the day for multiple days]

From these data I wanna gather them to be more readable, for that I'm creating another tab with the data merged into one row as shown below

[image: Expected result]

Obviously this has been done by hand.

I have seen numerous of exemple but each time someone provides the solution they simply copy/paste the formula without any explanation so it's impossible for me to understand how it works and adapt it to my situation...

One thing as well that would be nice to have but not mandatory is to be able to concatenate in the case there is multiple data in the same column for the same day, this way it avoid losing data.

EDIT: Here is an exemple sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-pfmQULjmp86siY96Jx4zy5sEqGHKy2eRoMlUlPJSPk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```cpp
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Data!A2:A;1));LAMBDA(day;{day\TOROW(FILTER(Data!B2:J;day=Data!A2:A);1;1)}))
```

Note that this formula is untested.

Comment: It throw an error unfortunately :/ I've adapted the "Data!" to the correct tab name but it doesn't change anything

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-pfmQULjmp86siY96Jx4zy5sEqGHKy2eRoMlUlPJSPk/edit?usp=sharing here it is. I'll add it to the og post as well

Comment: I copy-pasted my formula in tab z cell A2 and i'm not getting any error. Please replicate the error you are getting in the shared sheet.

Comment: There is something I don't understand, on the shared sheet it works perfectly as I've been able to do it on my side by copy pasting your formula.
On my own sheet it stays "Formula parse error", I thought maybe it was coming from the fact that it is a sheet create by google form so I've created a new one and it still doesn't work.
Is there an option or something to activate on the sheet for the lambda expression to work on any issue like this?

Comment: it's probably a locale issue, try the updated the formula.

Comment: Seems like the error is still there.
Here is the link of the test spreadsheet I've done locally maybe it could give you info https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fA9xDOXPa3XHcbpS5KaPt3BZCXE46JVgAOA7EVoH2NQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the formula you have in the sheet is the old one. I inserted the new one and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Seems all good indeed it was a different formula, idk why it wasn't updated on my side.
Thank you very much for your help! :)